# htaccess 301 redirect subdomain URL with variables to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have searched for a solution to redirect an URL containing a subdomain and a variable to a specific page on a new domain.

This is the URL that I want to redirect:
http://en.domain.com/?page=ceramic-vase

This is the URL I want to redirect to:
http://www.newdomain.com/en/ceramic-vase.php

I have tried with the basic that just redirects the entire subdomain, which works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/en/ [R=301,L]
```

I have then seen that in htaccess and mod_rewrite that the state [OR] is used - so I thought that [AND] might work too, but unfortunately not:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.domain.com  [AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=ceramic-vase$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/en/ceramic-vase/ [R=301,L]
```

I hope someone can help?

Comment: It's AND by default so have tried removing [AND] ?

Comment: Thanks @madpoet, I did not know that.
I updated my file to:

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.domain.com
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=ceramic-vases
#RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/en/ceramic-vase? [R=301,L]

This works like a charm! Will you place an answer, so I can close the post. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's AND by default so removing [AND] would be enough:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.domain.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=ceramic-vase$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/en/ceramic-vase/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =en.domain.com 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/en/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

- `%1` is back reference from query parameter `page`
- `?` in the end will strip off previous query string.